# MVC 5 for..loop ActionLink breaks html

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

The **ActionLink** not rendered well inside Foreach , when i remove it all thing works fine.

My Code

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (TBaseModel record in Model.Records.List())
    {

        <tr>
            <td>@record["RowID"].value</td>
            <td>@record["Usr_Username"].value</td>
            <td>@record["Usr_FullName"].value</td>
            <td>@record["Usr_Sec_Level_Label"].value</td>
            <td>@record["Usr_Department_Label"].value</td>
            <td>@record["Usr_Active_Label"].value</td>
            <td>
                <a href="@Html.Action("Admin_New_User", "Admin", new { id = @record["id"].value })" class="btn btn-xs btn-success"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</tbody>
```

What the problem is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html Action is used to render view not to create link , check here : [Html.Action And Html.RenderAction In ASP.NET MVC](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/html-action-and-html-renderaction-in-Asp-Net-mvc/)

you are trying to create `a` by your self than you should use

```
<a href="@Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName", new { id = "<id>" })">
  Edit
</a>
```

or just use

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "ActionMethod", "Controller",new { id = "<id>" }, null)
```

will generate

```
<a href="/controllerName/ActionMethod/<id>">Edit</a>
```